# How do I initialize cubejs library?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use this library to model and solve a cube from a string: https://github.com/ldez/cubejs but I have no clue how to include it on my website. I read the readme file and wrote this script:

```
Cube.initSolver();
var cube = new Cube();
cube = Cube.fromString(this.s); //s is a string from an external script in a format which should work
console.log('facelet: ' + cube.asString());
console.log('Solve: ' + cube.solve());
console.log('Is cube solved? ' + cube.isSolved());
```

I then included the js script in header of html:

```
<script src="js/solver.js"></script>
```

Is the script initialized or what?
console.log is there so that i could potentially see something happen but nope.
I really have no clue. all js files are in the same folder.

Comment: Are you getting an error in the console? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Im getting blank console logs so i dont know if its initialized or not